# CSS Menu bar border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have these small left and right borders either side of the text. Here is what I'm trying to make: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLI96.jpg

My problem is that the borders are not the same height of the surrounding div however they only go the same height of the text. Here is a screen shot: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQvS0.jpg

I have dried adding `height: 30px` to the `li` and `ul` however this does not change anything.

```css
*{margin:0;}

#header {
  width:100%;
}

#pre_header {
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#202020;
}
.pre_header_content {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:1040px;
}
#pre_header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height:30px;
}
#pre_header li {
  display: inline;
  border-right: .5px solid #414141;
  border-left: .5px solid #414141;
}
#pre_header a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  padding:6px 15px 6px 15px;
}
#pre_header a:hover {
  background-color:#4e4e4e;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="pre_header">
    <div class="pre_header_content">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="pages/#.php">Voucher codes</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/#.php">In-store codes</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/#.php">Online codes</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/#.php">Free samples</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/#.php">Advertise</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main_header">
    <div class="main_header_content">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone knows is there also anyway to bring the two borders together closer also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `padding:6px 15px 6px 15px;` to the `li` instead of `a`. And also, `0.5px` does not work. What's half a pixel? Updated your code. See below!

EDIT: **Note:** I also changed your hover effect to affect the `li` element instead of `a`.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
    width:100%;
}


#pre_header {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#202020;
}
.pre_header_content {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1040px;
}
#pre_header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height:30px;
}
#pre_header li {
    display: inline;
    border-right: 1px solid #414141;
    border-left: 1px solid #414141;
    padding: 0 15px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
#pre_header li:last-child{
  margin-right: 0;  
}
#pre_header a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    

}
#pre_header li:hover {
    background-color:#4e4e4e;

}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="pre_header">
        <div class="pre_header_content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="pages/#.php">Voucher codes</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/#.php">In-store codes</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/#.php">Online codes</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/#.php">Free samples</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/#.php">Advertise</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main_header">
        <div class="main_header_content">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great, Thankyou. Do you know how to reduce the gap size in-between the 2 borders next to each other ?

Comment: Yeah sure @BradleyCouisns, hold on I'll update my answer with a code for you

Comment: @BradleyCouisns Updated my answer. You have to set `box-sizing:border-box;` and then skip the top and bottom padding on the `li`. Then you set `float:left` on the `li` and adjust the `margin-right` to what you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change the li to display: inline-block; I've created a jsfiddle for you.

```
#pre_header li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #414141;
    border-left: 1px solid #414141;
}
```

Also, don't use .5px, use a single amount. I have used 1px.

http://jsfiddle.net/xeqsn83a/

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/yf0yvgLs/1/):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
}

#pre_header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #202020;
}

.pre_header_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1040px;
}

#pre_header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

#pre_header li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #414141;
    border-left: 1px solid #414141;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

#pre_header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#pre_header a:hover {
    background-color: #4e4e4e;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="pre_header">
        <div class="pre_header_content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="pages/#.php">Voucher codes</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/#.php">In-store codes</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/#.php">Online codes</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/#.php">Free samples</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/#.php">Advertise</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main_header">
        <div class="main_header_content">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I changed `display: inline` to `inline-block` for `li` and `border-width` to `1px` (it has to be an integer). Also made `li` items closer to each other with `font-size: 0` technique (read [this article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for understanding).

Comment: Thats great, Thankyou. Do you know how to reduce the gap size in-between the 2 borders next to each other ?

Comment: @BradleyCouisns yes, fixed my answer, check it out. I set `margin-right: 1px` for `#pre_header li` now, you can make it more or less.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the borders to touch, you would need to `float` it. And as others have mentioned, your border width needs to be an actual pixel size.  There is no such thing as .5px. Here is an example of what (I think) you are trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/tuc4Lwuu/

```
#pre_header li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #414141;
  border-left: 1px solid #414141;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```